# Use of .map with http in Angular 2

Tags: http, angular, subscribe

I want to know that do we really need `.map` when calling any api using `http` in `Angular 2`?
Please check my below code. It is working fine with `.map` and even without `.map`. If api returns data then it will return success else it will return error. I will also return any model data from here after performing some action. So, do I need `Observable` ? Is there any benefit of using it ? I am using `.subscribe` at `component` side to receive data. Is this fine or do I need any improvement ?

```
returnData: ReturnData;
callyAPI(body: modelData) {
     return this.http.post(URL, body)
           .do(data => {
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                   this.returnData.push(data[i]);
                }
                return this.returnData;
            },
               error => {});
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `map` but `do` is definitly the wrong operator here

`do` is supposed to execute some code for every event, but not to modify the events value, while `map` can update or replace the event by a different value like you do in your example.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/do.ts#L13-L14

> - Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return
> - an Observable that is identical to the source.

Comment: Your mean is that I can perform some code like `push` in `map` and then I return data directly from `.do`. Right ?

Comment: No, return in `do` is pointless because it is ignored. What you return in `map` replaces the event value though. I don't know what you mean with push. If you just want to add the event value to some local array then you can use `do`, `do` can't influence what the subscriber receives, while `map` can.

Comment: Here, I am receiving return from `do` to component `subscribe`.

Comment: Check my updated question. I am returning model and then I will accept it by using `subscribe` at component side.

Comment: But that's wrong. You should use a `map` for that. See also https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/do.ts#L55. The function passed is supposed to return `void`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to chat.

Comment: Ohkk. So, If I want to return data then I need to use `Observable`. is it ?

Comment: No, you need to use `map` instead of `do`

Comment: Ohk, got it. Thank you. :)